# SCP and UMASK Linux Centos

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, openssh, umask

I need to control the transferring of files on my server. Some files are sent through scp to my server and I want such a files to have a specific set of permissions let's say 770. I tried `pam_umask.so` in `/etc/pam.d/login` and setting `umask` in `/etc/profile` but it seems to not work.

Which is the best way on Linux to force an umask for files transferred via scp?

Regards,
Andrea

Comment: did you also add `session optional pam_umask.so umask=770` to `/etc/pam.d/common_session`?

Comment: There's no common_session on centos 5, I added the pam_umask in the system-auth but it's not working :-(

Comment: Could you try to put the config directly into `/etc/pam.d/sshd`? That is the place where the config should end up finally.

(on my distro, which is not centos, I have `common-session` file which is included in the other configs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `scp` does not initialize a shell, thus don't source any file such as `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`.

So the only way of doing this, as commented by Stefan Ferstl, seems to use the pam module `pam_umask.so`.

The file `/etc/pam.d/sshd` is probably the best place to do it, if you want to limit this behavior to ssh sessions :

```
session optional pam_umask.so umask=0007
```

Comment: Actually, scp runs another copy of scp on the remote system, and the  remote process would be launched as a shell command. If the remote user's shell is `bash` for example, it would start up as a non-interactive, non-login process. It ought to read .bashrc in this case, but not .bash_profile or the other files sourced for login sessions.

Comment: Well, it doesn't on my system, using openssh. The session is opened on the remote system by `sshd` which launches `scp` directly, without a shell. And `.bashrc` isn't sourced.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eBr273CD. It may not be obvious that bash is being used because it optimizes this case, and doesn't fork before exec'ing scp.

Comment: Still, I didn't manage to set the permissions mask through `.bashrc`. I'll look into that again when I have some time to do more tests.

Comment: In my testing, this approach can **reduce permissions** but not **expand permission**.  A umask of `0007` will change uploaded files from 777 to 770, but a umask of `0000` will not change a file from 770 to 777.  Setting perms explicitly (`chmod ... ; scp -p`) seems to be the only option.